# Wamp localhost editing send me to WAMPSERVER Homepage

Tags: apache, wamp

I want to change the adress of my website from http://localhost/tests/home.html
to www.mywebsite.com.

I edited the following files as explained :

```
C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17\conf\httpd.conf
C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

However, i'm not redirected to home.html but to the Wamp Server Homepage.
Any idea on how to solve this ? For info, here's my `httpd-vhosts.conf` and `hosts` file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.mywebsite.com
DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www/tests
<Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/tests/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
</Directory>
```

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 tests
127.0.0.1 www.mywebsite.com

::1 localhost
::1 tests
::1 www.mywebsite.com
```

Also, note that there are more than one files in my `www/tests` folder, but i want to access to home.html specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need a VH definition fot localhost when you create virtual hosts

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And the Server name should be `mywebsite.com` with a `ServerAlias` if you want to use the `www.www.mywebsite.com`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mywebsite.com
    ServerAlias www.mywebsite.com
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www/tests
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/tests/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Hosts file changes

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 tests
127.0.0.1 mywebsite.com

::1 localhost
::1 tests
::1 mywebsite.com
```

Once these are chnaged, remember to reset the dnscache

```
net stop dnscache
net start dnscache
```

And the restart Apache to pick up these chnages

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> Restart Service
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll add that your main page needs to be named "index.php", though there must be a way to change that.

Comment: Yes it does and yes it can be changed, but thats pretty universal to web servers so I would not suggest you make that change.